# How do I determine the line number where a string exists in a text file?

Tags: php, file

I know how to search for, open and check whether any files contain the string "test", but I can't for the life of me figure out how to determine the *line number* where "test" exists. (Or where it first exists, if there are multiple instances.)

*I need this because I finally had enough of wasting my time with a combination of Notepad++'s search feature and Windows' awful search feature, and instead decided to make my own, specifically tailored for my needs, allowing me to search both file names and contents from all the places where I need to look at once. And then it just opens the found files and goes directly to the right line. This will save so much time if I can get it working. I'm at the last step now.*

Answer (score 2):

Assume the file `test.txt` has the following content and our search string as `abc`:

```
abc
def 
abc xyz
xyaabcdeejwgrf
```

If you want search results as below where `abc` even as a substring is fine:

```
abc was found at line 1
abc was found at line 3
abc was found at line 4
```

then we could simply iterate over the file line by line keeping a counter of line number and print the results.

```
<?php


$file_handler = fopen("test.txt","r");

if($file_handler === false){
    die("File doesn't exist!");
}

$search_str = "abc";
$line_no = 0;

while(!feof($file_handler)){
    $line_no++;
    $line = fgets($file_handler);
    if(strpos($line,$search_str) !== false) echo "$search_str was found at ",$line_no,PHP_EOL;
}

fclose($file_handler);
```

If you want search results to be an exact match of `abc`:

```
abc was found at line 1
abc was found at line 3
```

then we could do a simple regex match with the help of [word boundaries `\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html).

```
<?php


$file_handler = fopen("test.txt","r");

if($file_handler === false){
    die("File doesn't exist!");
}

$search_str = "abc";
$line_no = 0;

while(!feof($file_handler)){
    $line_no++;
    $line = fgets($file_handler);
    if(preg_match('/\b'.$search_str.'\b/', $line) == 1) echo "$search_str was found at line ",$line_no,PHP_EOL;
}

fclose($file_handler);
```

You could also add a `break` in the while loop if you want only first occurrence.